# Do self-loops in DFA cause infinite languages?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

A true/false question: If a DFA $M$ contains a self-loop on some state $q$, then $M$ must accept an infinite language.

The answer is "false". I've read [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/infinite-language-vs-finite-language), but I'm still wondering why $M$ does not necessarily accept an infinite language. Isn't the language $b^*$ infinite? Don't all self-loops look like $b^*$?

Comment: If your definition of DFA demands the graph to be complete (i.e. the transition function to be total), *every* minimal DFA will contain self-loops.

Comment: @Raphael If a self-loop is a transition from a state to itself, then consider the minimal DFA accepting $\mathcal{L} = \{ a^{2n} \}$.  This DFA contains two states and no self-loops.

Comment: @PålGD Oh, right; my argument only seems to work for languages that don't contain a word for every possible prefix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the answer is False:

consider a DFA that has no accepting states at all: any loop is not relevant, the language will always be the empty set.

Another option - a loop on a *dead* state, etc.

However, if it contains a loop on an "accepting path", then indeed the language must be infinite. (this is actually the key idea behind the pumping lemma..)

Comment: To generalize, any state that either isn't reachable from the start state, or that cannot reach any accept state can be have self-loops without any immediate consequence.  A very easy exercise:  Consider the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a\}$ and construct a DFA that accepts the language $\mathcal{L} = \{a\}$.