# Do all DFA's containing an "accepting path containing a cycle" accept infinite languages?

Tags: computability, automata, finite-automata

So I've seen this claim being made on different questions:

[Do self-loops in DFA cause infinite languages?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/do-self-loops-in-dfa-cause-infinite-languages)

I'd like to find formal proof for this.

I think I should also note that an "accepting path containing a cycle" is probably defined as a path in a graph so that the states in the DFA  are  nodes in the graph and there must be a cycle and at least one accepting state in that path.

Comment: An accepting path is a path from the initial state to an accepting state. Perhaps this will help you prove the claim.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? whether the statement 'All DFA's containing cycles define an infinite language' is true or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DFA contains a path from the start node to an accepting state that contains a cycle, then the DFA is an infinite language.  The proof is easy: you can go around the cycle as many times as you like.  Depending on how many times you go around the cycle, you get a different word accepted by the DFA; the more times around the cycle, the longer the word (so it has to be different from any word where you went around the cycle a different number of times). There are infinitely many possibilities for how many times you can choose to go around the cycle, so infinitely many words accepted by the DFA.