# Determining if an NFA accepts an infinite language in polynomial time

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, polynomial-time, infinity

Can we determine in polynomial time if the language accepted by an NFA is infinite?

The case of DFA is simple, but converting an NFA to a DFA may take  exponential time.
Also, I ran into this post,
[Determine if an NFA accepts infinite language in polynomial time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117241/determine-if-an-nfa-accepts-infinite-language-in-polynomial-time).
But there is no solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\epsilon$-transitions can be removed in polynomial time, let us assume for simplicity that the NFA does not contain any $\epsilon$-transitions (though the argument can be modified to accommodate them).

Suppose that the NFA contains $n$ states, and denote by $L$ the language it accepts. If $L$ is infinite then it contains some word $w$ of length at least $n$. An accepting path of $w$ necessarily passes through the same state twice. This means that there are three states $q_i,q,q_f$, where $q_i$ is initial and $q_f$ is final, and paths $q_i \to^* q$, $q \to^+ q$, and $q \to^* q_f$ (the second one should be non-empty). Conversely, if such states exist, then $L$ is infinite. You can determine whether such states exist in polynomial time, since reachability is in polynomial time.

Answer (score 6):

An NFA (with $\epsilon$-moves or not) can be viewed naturally as a directed multi-graph.  We will use "state" and "node" interchangeably.

Whether an NFA accepts an infinite language is the same as whether there is a path from the initial state to an accepting state that contains at least one state that is a part of a cycle. Here **we consider a self-loop as a cycle**. See Yuval's answer for a simple proof.

##### An algorithm in polynomial time

A DFS from the initial state can determine all states that are reachable from the initial state.
A DFS from each state can determine whether the NFA can reach an accepting state from that state.
For each state, we can use a depth-first-search (DFS) to determine whether it is a part of a cycle.
If there is a state which is reachable from the initial state and from which the NFA can reach an accepting state and which is a part of a cycle, the answer is Yes. Otherwise, the answer is No.

##### An algorithm in linear time

For every ordered nodes $s_1$ and $s_2$ in the directed multi-graph, we can replace all edges from $s_1$ to $s_2$ by a single edge from $s_1$ to $s_2$, which transforms the directed multi-graph into a directed graph without multi-edges (with self-loops possibly). This transformation does not affect paths nor cycles.

Call the transformed graph $H$.

A DFS on $H$ from the initial state can mark all reachable accepting states. Another DFS on $H$ starting from an additional node, "the super-accepting state" that is connected from all accepting states, treating each edge backwards, can mark all states from which the NFA can reach an accepting state. A state is marked by both DFS iff there is a path from the initial state to an accepting state that contains that state.

A state is a part of a cycle iff it is a part of a cyclic [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) (SCCs). An SCC is called cyclic if it contains a cycle, i.e., if it contains either a self-loop or more than one node. We can adapt easily any one of common [linear-time algorithms that find all SCCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#DFS-based_linear-time_algorithms)  to find all cyclic SCCs with the same time-complexity.

If there is a state that is marked by both DFS and is part of a cyclic SCC, the answer is Yes. Otherwise the answer is No.

Since each of the transformation, both DFSs, the adapted SCC-finding algorithm and the final check runs in linear time, the entire algorithm runs in linear time.